# How can I easily produce "Balsamiq style" wireframe mockups in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What is the easiest way without vector? I would like to generate something very similar to the image below for CSS development, but I'm having a hard time figuring out the easiest way to turn shape lines into pencil or sketched look lines.

[image: pencil lines]

I've tried:

1. Using calligraphy pens, held down the shift key
2. Hand tracing a straight line but it came up too jagged

I feel like I'm making this unnecessarily hard. Any thoughts are generously and gratefully accepted.

Comment: Is there a reason for you wanting to create this in Photoshop instead of using tools that were developed for wireframing, like [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/) or [Pencil project](http://pencil.evolus.vn/)?

Comment: I'm comfortable in Photoshop regarding basic mockups and designs. I know there's 1000 different choices out there but this one works for me. I'll check out those tools, but I'm trying to mix pencil style with the flat style without these different trends interfering too much.

Comment: Or you could buy Balsamiq, which has been specifically designed to do stuff like this.

Answer (score 5):

You could apply a Wave distort to the outline of a shape in order to systematically achieve a similar effect.

#### Step 1: Prepare your layers

*Starting with the straight borders, I'd first convert the rasterized lines to smart objects so that this process can be reversed.*

[image: Screenshot of step 1]

#### Step 2: Apply a Wave Distort to one of the layers

**Filter** → **Distort** → ***Wave...***

*You'll have to fiddle with the settings to achieve the desired appearance*

[image: Screenshot of Wave Distort menu]

#### Step 3: Repeat as necessary for each layer

*You should click **Randomize** each time so that they don't all follow the same wave distort*

[image: Screenshot of step 3]

#### Finished Product:

[image: Result:]

The ***Amplitude*** setting within the Wave dialog box will control how far the wave can be from the center of the original straight line. This will help you make it "pixel perfect".